# Fetch data from JSON in swift 3

Tags: ios, json, iphone, swift, swift3

I am new to iOS and my task is to fetch data from JSON. I have one JSON and from that I am able to get some data but some no. Please help me .[image]

[image: Response from JSON]

In this I used code :

```
              NetworkManager.post("http://dev.depolitie.be/dev/public/api/cameras/get_cameras_list", parameters: parameters as [String : AnyObject], success: {(result: NSDictionary) -> Void in
        print ("Api Success 22  : result is:\n \(result)")

        if let error = result.value(forKey: "error") {
            print(error)
        }else {

            let userDict = result.value(forKey: "data") as! NSDictionary
           self.cameraArray = userDict["data"] as! NSArray


            let introText = userDict["introtext"] as? Int

            print("introtext",introText)


             //let firstName = employee["firstName"]! as Strin
            //  let introtext = userDataAsArray["introtext"]! as Int
           // print("introText", introtext)


        }

        self.cameraTableView.reloadData()

    }, failure: {(error: NSDictionary?) -> Void in
        print ("Api Failure : error is:\n \(String(describing: error))")

    })
```

The inner data I get by initialising it as array but I am not able to get  "introtext" field from JSON.

Comment: A quick look at your JSON shows that "introtext" is a text (as its name suggests) but in your code you're trying to decode it as an Int. This can't work...

Comment: I think your introtext is inside the root dictionary, also you need to cast to the proper type String in this case

Comment: Please include where you are getting this exact JSON from so that we can examine it properly.  Right now, it is an image file (we need exact text from the same place you are getting it) and it looks like it contains errors.

Comment: I tried to get  it as String but I am getting error.  @Moritz

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper Look at Reinier Melian's comment, I think he's right. This field is not inside userDict.

Comment: Yes, my text is inside the root directory but not able to get the data. @ReinierMelian

Comment: @Moritz check My updated image of full response from JSON

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper check my answer and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
NetworkManager.post("http://dev.depolitie.be/dev/public/api/cameras/get_cameras_list", parameters: parameters as [String : AnyObject], success: {(result: NSDictionary) -> Void in
    print ("Api Success 22  : result is:\n \(result)")

    if let error = result.value(forKey: "error") {
        print(error)
    }else {

    let userDict = result.value(forKey: "data") as! NSDictionary        
    let dataArray = userDict["data"] as! NSArray
    let firstElementOfDataArray = dataArray.object(at: 0) as! NSDictionary

    let adminId = firstElementOfDataArray["admin_id"] as! String
    let createdAt = firstElementOfDataArray["created_at"] as! String
    let description = firstElementOfDataArray["description"] as! String







    }

    self.cameraTableView.reloadData()

}, failure: {(error: NSDictionary?) -> Void in
    print ("Api Failure : error is:\n \(String(describing: error))")

})
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment your `introtext` is inside the root dictionary, also you need to cast to the proper type `String` in this case

Try with this code

```
if let error = result.value(forKey: "error") {
            print(error)
        }else {

           if let userDict = result["data"] as? [String:AnyObject]{
              if let cameraArrayValues = userDict["data"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]{
                   self.cameraArray = cameraArrayValues
               }
           }

           if let introText = result["introtext"] as? String{
               print("Introtext:" + introText)
           }

        }
```

Comment: Please don't adopt bad habits like `valueForKey` and `NSArray / NSDictionary`. Suggest the appropriate Swift syntax.

Comment: sorry I just copy and paste the chunk of code from the OP question, and change the relevant part, but i will fix now this, thanks @vadian